# Retrive data from a xml in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have a xml request tags like this:

```
<request>

<name>john</name>
<age>22</age>

</request>
```

i want to get the data from xmla tags like this

```
var name=john
var age=22
```

how i can parse the xml in node.js

Comment: With stuff like this, your best bet is googling something like `node xml parser npm`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id recommend looking into some NPM packages that solve this problem.

Having a look into some of the packages on NPM, this seems to be a **very** popular package to solve your problem:

[xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)

This package has over **6 million** downloads per week that suggests its both a capable package and one that will more than likely remain actively maintained.